# ssh: connect to host example port 22: Connection refused

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, localhost, ssh-keys

I have given the following command in the terminal:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8888 bb@example
```

However, the following error appears:

```
ssh: connect to host example port 22: Connection refused
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep openssh-server
```

But the following error appears:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

When I type

```
sudo service ssh status
```

, This is the error I get:

```
sudo: service: command not found
```

Comment: 1) Which one of the computers involved is macOS? What OS is the other one running? 2) Are you trying the 2nd and 3rd commands on your own computer, or physically on the `example` server? 3) What was the _full_ output of the command that produced the Java error?

Comment: I'm trying to get connected to another server using macOS. All these commands are on my own computer. I have already written the full command.

Comment: The OS of the other server is Ubuntu 18.

Comment: `localhost` is shorthand for 'me'. It won't connect to any other machine/VM except itself. After that, it's really not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is the server actually named "example"? If you run `ping example`, does that reach the server? Also, as I commented [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871877/ssh-connect-to-host-example-port-22-connection-refused), `apt` and `service` are not relevant on macOS (and since the macOS computer isn't the server, trying to install/start ssh service on it isn't relevant anyway).